# VueJs 3 + Vuetify: Not working in IE and Edge

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vuetify.js, polyfills

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have VueJs 3 with Vuetify. Works great with Chrome and Firefox, but it is not loading in IE and Edge. I am attempting to load polyfills with Babel and forcing Vue CLI to transpile dependencies for Vuetify.

*package.json*

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports: {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']
}
```

*main.ts*

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

The imports are included at the top of my main.ts file. I have been using the official documentation to set this up.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? I see that you decided to just remove Vuetify, but that doesn't solve the problem for you or anyone else who doesn't have this working.

Comment: I don't remember exactly since this was so long ago now, but I believe I was receiving some sort of console error that gave me a clue that Vuetify was causing the issue. I do remember that the app would just not load at all in IE/Edge and Vue was not being executed. It would just be the default index.html file that was rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created the project using vue-cli and added vuetify using `vue add vuetify`, then the solution to make it work in Edge should be to add `transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']` to the vue.config.js file.

But in my case I added vue/vuetify to an already existing project and did not use vue-cli. So to make it work I installed core-js `npm install core-js@2 --save` and added this to the rules in my webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules\\(?!(vuetify)).*/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                configFile: './babel.config.js',
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I added the babel.config.js file to the root of the project.

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
            debug: true,
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            corejs: { "version": 2, "proposals": true }
        }],
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
    ]
}
```

A little late reply, but I couldn't find this solution anywhere else and this was one of the first posts showing up when I was searching for it myself. So I figured I'll post what worked for me here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the solution. Yes this is exactly what I did. I added Vuetify to an already existing project. I will have to try this out on a rainy day.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just removing Vuetify (I was only using one feature from it which was easily replaced) and using the babel polyfill cdn. Probably not the best solution but got it working for now.